# WSDL Import Error - Book Car Reservation

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, sabre

I'm having an issue when I try to run wsdl.exe to generate code for the Book Car Reservation service. I don't have this problem with any of the other services.

I'm using the following command in a VS2015 Developer Command Prompt:

```
wsdl -n:SabreWebservices -o=Sabre.cs http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/tpfc/OTA_VehResLLS2.0.2RQ.wsdl
```

The command returns the following error:

```
Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
R2028, R2029: A DESCRIPTION using the WSDL namespace and the WSDL SOAP binding namespace MUST be valid according to the XML Schemas found at http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/2003-02-11.xsd and http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/2003-02-11.xsd.
  -  Warning: The element 'message' in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' has invalid child element 'part'. List of possible elements expected: 'documentation, part' in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' as well as any element in namespace '##other'. Line 12, position 4.
  -  Warning: The element 'message' in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' has invalid child element 'part'. List of possible elements expected: 'documentation, part' in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' as well as any element in namespace '##other'. Line 17, position 4.

For more details on the WS-I Basic Profile v1.1, see the specification at http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html.

Error: Unable to import binding 'OTA_VehResSoapBinding' from namespace 'https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc'.
  - Unable to import operation 'OTA_VehResRQ'.
  - Missing message part 'header' for message 'OTA_VehResInput' from namespace '
https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc'.
Parameter name: partName
```

Comment: Not sure about the exact problem for .NET/C#, but you can contact support at: https://developer.sabre.com/contact
Or by email to: webservices.support@sabre.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll try contacting Sabre directly!